# What are some good use cases for Querydsl?

Tags: java, querydsl

I read about the runtime query builder [querydsl](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/3.2.2/reference/html/ch01s02.html). But I could not figure out the best cases or examples, where querydsl is most useful. If somebody can explain, it would be really good.

Comment: Any time you want type-safe SQL statements inside your Java code and want full control over the statements sent to the database (try to use common table expressions or window functions using JPQL)

Comment: I do not get why people vote for closing this question, The advantages of querydsl are not documented on the website.

Comment: @aviad: there **are** some links covering that right on their homepage, e.g.: http://www.hascode.com/2014/02/creating-elegant-typesafe-queries-for-jpa-mongodbmorphia-and-lucene-using-querydsl/ or

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name true. However, I would expect something on the frontpage that explains the purpose and the benefits in few lines rather than expecting the first time visitor to iterate through all blog post links.

Answer (score 2):

Querydsl helps you to get rid of hard-coded queries and provides a library that encapsulates the functionality of SQL through the hierarchy of corresponding types and interfaces.

It is a better practice to code your queries using interfaces and parametrize the calls. 
You will be able to auto-test your changes during the build time using JUnits.
The above makes querying more robust and improves the maintainability of your codebase.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to create dynamic database queries, you should use Querydsl.

The pros of using Querydsl are:

- It supports dynamic queries.
- It has a very clean API. In other words, it is easy to create complex
  queries with Querydsl, and the query generation code is easy to read.
- It also supports JDO, Lucene, and MongoDB.

The only “problem” of Querydsl is that it isn’t the standard way to create dynamic queries with the Java Persistence API.

Quite fine tutorial with very good explanation you can find [here](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-part-five-querydsl/).

Answer (score 0):

QueryDSL is type-safe queries purely in Java, no strings involved.

```
repository.findAll(QProduct.product.owner.name.startsWith("Hello"));
```

So when is it a good idea to use it?

Whenever you need to query from a database that is supported by QueryDSL, of course. Why use SQL when you can use QueryDSL?